# Can FX send be used as an extra AUX send on mixer?

Tags: mixer, live, monitoring, aux-sends

We have the Allen & Heath PA28 in our church.

We use the two FB1 & FB2 outputs for our primary stage monitors.

We have one other AUX output that are using for recording purposes.

Now we are in need of additional monitor for the choir and possibly one more for the musicians.

Can we use the FX out for this? Or is there any other way to get more aux mixes out? Using some external device? Im kinda new to this :)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to [the manual](http://www.allen-heath.com/media/PA_User_Guide.pdf), page 20, the FX output on the mixer is **before** the internal effects processing, so you may use that output as an AUX too.

You could perhaps free up the other AUX send by using the 2TRK Out option for recording instead.

Also, if you don't mind the mix being mono, there is a pretty neat trick: use L for the P.A. and R for the recording. This way you will not take up any aux/sends etc. and you will still be able to adjust levels differently (because it is likely that you will be compensating for the stage sound level on the P.A. mix)

Here is a passage on that from the manual (page 24):

> Using L and R in church sound A method popular with some small to
>   medium sized churches is to use the L fader to control a mono “Live”
>   mix for the house reinforcement, and the R fader to adjust a
>   “Recording” mix for the ministry tape. It enables the operator to
>   easily carry out both jobs with one console. The channel PAN controls
>   are used to make adjustments between what is heard by the congregation
>   and what is recorded to tape. This method offers several advantages
>   which are described in detail on the JdB Sound web site:
>   http://www.jdbsound.com/art/art511.html

Comment: Oh..!! Thanks :) Btw What's the 2TRK out for? How does it work?

Comment: Well, it records the sum of your fader mix (i.e. the master). If you set it to Pre LR your main level adjustments during show will not affect the recorded levels. I updated the post with some other approach to the recording set up.